# Can't access to the Solr admin panel - HTTP Status 403

Tags: tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I am using the Solr in my web application. Previously I used Tomcat 6 for working the Solr. After migration to Tomcat7, the Solr admin panel became inaccessible.

When I'm trying to access the admin panel by the http://myproject.local:3080/solr I've got an error:

```
HTTP Status 403 -
type Status report
message
description Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

I reviewed all related configs, checked all paths, changed owner for some Tomcat paths, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show Solr logs?

Answer (score 1):

Check tomcat-users.xml for solr user

Also check if there is security valve set on solr server.xml
something like `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1″/>`
solr access might be working but only from localhost

Answer (score 0):

@pguzun some pointers:

- Is that a fresh Tomcat installation?
- Did you copy the Solr webapp under the webapps folder?
- Is the webapp folder called "solr"? and not "solr-3-6-1" or something like that?
- Do you have some general webapp settings?

Solr webapp doesn't have any security restriction. I'm talking about Solr 1.4.* - 4.10.* because I don't know Solr 5, but I guess you fall in one of those version because version 5 comes with an embedded servlet engine (Jetty)

The 403 error code comes from these kind of sources:

- webapp: unless you changed the Solr web deployment descriptor this option  is not valid
- tomcat: general settings on tomcat, and here my question about the fresh installation: that's strange because the download bundle doesn't enable security so here something happened (an installation previously used for other purposes?)
- I see in some tomcat versions (but I don't remember well which version) this error occurring when the context root of the webapp is not what you think.